# Python string and UTF-8 problems

Tags: python, utf-8

I am programming a script that will grab some data from my website using http GET.

My problem is that i have to pass unicode characters to the website.

I am reading a file that contains these characters and then i try produce a url in order to make the request.

The file is utf-8 encoded and i use this to read from it

```
f = codecs.open("values.txt", encoding='utf-8')
```

then i read the first line of the file and i am concatenating the value with the url

```
sUrl = "http://example.com?word="
value = f.readline()
visitUrl = sUrl + value
```

if i use `print visitUrl` the output is correct. i.e http://example.com?word=π

How to use `visiUrl` without destroying my special characters? 
I tried to encode the string to ascii but it doesn't work for all characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) the url

```
import urllib
s = u'Здравей'
urllib.quote(s.encode('utf-8'))
# %D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9
```

or use [urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) directly to build the query part of the url

```
urllib.urlencode({'data': s.encode('utf-8')})
# 'data=%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9'
```

Comment: should i choose urllib or urllib2?

Comment: @messkech: Those functions are in `urllib`. Don't let the name of `urllib2` confuse you that it's an alternative library - it's actually an extension of `urllib` and both libraries have been merged in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Build the URL with [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) rather than trying to construct it by concatenating strings. Non-ASCII characters in a URL need to be URL encoded.